# C- Save string to array and print a char

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, character

Im trying to save a 100 character max string into an array and then print an specified character of the array via an index, yet I get Segmentation error 11, here is the code:`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   char str1[100];
   int index;
   printf("Enter text of max 100 characters: \n");
   scanf("%s", str1);

   printf("Enter the index to search\n");
   scanf("%d", &index);

   printf("your char is: %c\n", str1[index]);

   return(0);
}
```

`
Any suggestions?

Comment: `char str1[100];` --> `char str1[100+1];` (and `scanf("%s", str1);` --> `scanf("%100s", str1);`)

Comment: For reasonable inputs, no problem. Please post *in the question* the inputs you made, what you expected, and what happened. Preferably, work with `char str1[10];` etc while debugging.

Comment: in general, avoid using `scanf`. it is very easy to overflow your arrays with it. use fgets instead and sscanf afterwards.

Comment: `scanf` is not easily overflowed if you properly specify the *field width*.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow.  Such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: after the user enters the 'index', check that the index is less than the `strlen()` of the string entered by the user.

Comment: NOTE: the max number of characters that the user can enter is 99, not 100 as `scanf()` will append a NUL byte to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While user input is generally better handled by reading input with `fgets` and then parsing what you need from the resulting buffer with `sscanf` of simply with a pair of pointers and "inch-worming down" (a/k/a "walking") the string testing each char and handling as needed -- it is always worth a look at `scanf` to detail what you need to do to successfully use it for user input.

While `fgets` is not without needed validations, the number and types of validations needed with `scanf` and handling of characters that remain in the input buffer in the different cases of *input failure* or *matching failures* create a number of extra pitfalls for new (and not so new) C programmers.

The two primary problems with `scanf` are (1) there is no default limitation on the number of characters that it will read into any buffer (potentially overflowing your array); and (2) the fact that it does not remove the trailing `'\n'` (or any of the characters following an *input* or *matching* failure) from the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`). It is **up to you** to account for all characters in the input buffer and empty the buffer as needed.

Further complicating the picture are the ways the different `scanf` **format specifiers** handle *leading-whitespace* (numeric conversions typically skip leading whitespace, while a character conversion won't) Another issue is handling *included* whitespace. The `"%s"` format specifier will only read up to the first whitespace encountered, making it impossible to read `"My dog has fleas"` with a single `%s` specifier. (you can use a *character class* to read included whitespace -- as shown in the example below)

There are many other *subtleties* with `scanf` as well, so it is well worth the time it takes to read and understand `man scanf`.

From the comments, you now know if you ask for a string of `100` chars, you need, at minimum, `101` characters of storage -- we will assume that is learned.

When taking any input with `scanf`, you must always **validate the return** to insure that the number of conversion expected, in fact took place. For example, if you are reading `"5 dogs"` with the conversion specifier `"%d %s"`, a return of `2` indicates a successful conversion to integer and string. However, you also know, at minimum a `'\n'` remains in the input buffer (and potentially many more characters, if say, `"5 dogs and cats"` were entered. It is up to you to remove the `'\n'` and any other characters that remain, before attempting to read more input with `scanf`.

The following example captures most of the pitfalls with your example and provides a couple of tools you can use when dealing with user input. The bottom line is learn to use `fgets`, but know how to use `scanf` as well. Your goal is to provide as robust and bullet-proof input routine as you can. Think about all the dumb things a user might do when prompted for input (or heaven forbid, a cat walks across the keyboard) There are always more validations you can add. Look at each of the included validations, and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 100    /* if you need a constant, declare one  */

/* helper function to remove any chars left in input buffer */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    char str1[MAXC+1] = ""; /* initialize to all zero */
    int index, rtn, len;    /* index, return, length  */

    for (;;) {  /* loop until valid input obtained */
        printf ("Enter text of max 100 characters: ");
        rtn = scanf ("%100[^\n]", str1);    /* read at most MAXC char */

        if (rtn != 1) {         /* validate scanf return */
            if (rtn == EOF) {   /* check if EOF, ctrl+d, ctrl+z (windoze) */
                printf ("input canceled.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            if (!str1[0])       /* was a character entered? */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: string is empty.\n");
            /* remove '\n' and any chars that remain in stdin */
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else {  /* all conditions met, good entry, empty stdin and break */
            empty_stdin();
            break;
        }
    }

    len = (int)strlen (str1);   /* get string length */

    for (;;) {  /* now do the same thing for integer */
        printf ("Enter the index to search (0-%d): ", len - 1);
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &index)) != 1) {
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                printf ("input canceled.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - not integer.\n");
            /* only need to strip if non-integer entered, because %d
             * will skip leading whitespace, including '\n'.
             */
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else if (index < 0 || len < index + 1)  /* validate index value */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid index - out of range.\n");
        else
            break;
    }

    printf ("your char is: %c\n", str1[index]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanfstr1
Enter text of max 100 characters: 12345678901234567890
Enter the index to search (0-19): -1
error: invalid index - out of range.
Enter the index to search (0-19): 0
your char is: 1

$ ./bin/scanfstr1
Enter text of max 100 characters: 12345678901234567890
Enter the index to search (0-19): foo
error: invalid input - not integer.
Enter the index to search (0-19): 6
your char is: 7

$ ./bin/scanfstr1
Enter text of max 100 characters: My dog has fleas.
Enter the index to search (0-16): d
error: invalid input - not integer.
Enter the index to search (0-16): 3
your char is: d

$ ./bin/scanfstr1
Enter text of max 100 characters:
error: string is empty.
Enter text of max 100 characters: My cats are fine.
Enter the index to search (0-16): meow
error: invalid input - not integer.
Enter the index to search (0-16): input canceled.
```